# Cards and Choices not displayed in Skype for business (Bot Framework)

Tags: botframework

I recently add the skype for business channel to my bot, however Choices prompts and Hero Cards are not displayed in the message

```
   intents.matches(/^test/, [
  function (session) {
    const leaves = ['Holiday', 'Medical', 'Meeting', 'Seminar'];
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Please select a leave request', leaves, { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
  },
  function (session, args) {
    session.endDialog(`You are taking a ${args.response.entity} leave`);
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue, Did you find an alternate method like rendering HTML inside bot?

Comment: Hi, no i didn’t, we dropped skype for business at that moment, and stopped the project later

Comment: oh god. thanks for reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Skype for Business channel for Bot Framework is currently under Developer Preview.

Per the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview#feature-support):

> **Cards and buttons** : Skype for Business does not support cards and buttons in the Developer Preview. For the Developer Preview, cards and
>   buttons are not shown to the user if they are sent by a bot. Cards and
>   buttons fallback to text support will be added soon.